# mouseup event is not triggered after scroll bar moves in IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did a search in the site but didn't get useful info for my case. A simple demo can be found at [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/chennanfei/CmW9e/). When I moved onto the div scroll bar and pressed the mouse, the event 'mousedown' was fired. And then I scrolled the bar, released the mouse. Unfortunately the event 'mouseup' was not fired in IE/Safari. Chrome and Firefox work fine. Is there a work-around solution for IE and Safari? Thanks!

Sample Code :

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">
    </div>
</div>
<p id="text"></p>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $txt = $('#text');
    $('.box').mouseup(function() {
        $txt.text('mouseup');
    });

    $('.box').mousedown(function() {
        $txt.text('mousedown');
    });
});
```

---

Did more search in the site and got similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7498594/1137191). A [`solution`](http://jsfiddle.net/chennanfei/gLAC7/3/) proposed in the question is not prefect but worthy of trying.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $txt = $('#text'), $win = $(window), $doc = $(document);
    $win.on('mousedown', function(event) {
        $txt.text('mousedown');

        if(event.pageX < ($win.width() - 10)) {
            return;
        }

        $doc.on('mousemove', function(event) {
            if(event.pageX < ($win.width() - 10)){
                //mouse is off scrollbar
                $(this).unbind(event);
                $win.trigger('mouseup', ['manual fire']);
            }
        });
    }).on('mouseup', function(event, str) {
        $txt.text('mouseup: ' + str);
    });
});
```

Comment: Just tried to fix this, to no avail. Useful read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145402/mouseup-bug-in-all-browsers-except-firefox

Comment: Why you need this?, I mean what you want from 'mouseup' event, instead you can use the 'scroll' event if you want to do something on scroll finish.

Comment: @ucdream did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same trouble in IE11 and looking for a decent solution.

Answer (score 2):

the `mouseup` fired for me in Safari... I can't test in IE as I'm on a Mac, but please try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CmW9e/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $txt = $('#text');

    $('.box').on("mousedown.box", function() {

        $txt.text('mousedown');

        $(document).one("mouseup.box", function() {
            $txt.text('mouseup');
        });

    });


});
```

Basically binding the `mouseup` to the `Document` when you `mousedown`and then removing the bind after it's triggered :) this way the `mouseup` will ***always*** trigger no matter where the mouse is

Comment: Changed the `.on` to `.one` to utilize jQuery's own event removal, and make code slightly cleaner... _also I changed the original binding to `.on()`for consistency - not important_